# Unity - Show a sprite when screen is touched

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, rendering, sprite

what I want to achieve is **showing** a sprite when the screen is touched by the player and **make it disappear** when a character reached the sprite's position, I made a pic to picture my words if I was not clear :

[image: image screen]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1) To show sprite use

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    { gameObjectToShow.SetActive(true); }
```

2) To disapper it: add Collider to gameObjectToShow (2D Box or Circle), make it trigger, increase radius of that Collider and use OnTriggerEnter with gameObjectToShow.SetActive(false);

Answer (score 0):

To add previous answer:
you should raycast from you touch position:

```
void Update()
{
    Ray raycast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
    RaycastHit raycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
    {
        if (raycastHit.transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>())
        {
            sprite.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```